# How to request a single document by _id via alias?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Is it possible to request a single document by its id by querying an alias, provided that all keys across all indices in the alias are unique (it is an external guarantee)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, querying an alias spanning over multiple indices work the same way as querying one indice.

Just do this query over the alias:

```
POST my_alias_name/_search
{
    "filter":{
        "term":{"_id": "AUwNrOZsm6BwwrmnodbW"}
    }
}
```

EDIT: GET operations are not real searches and can't be done on aliases spanning over multiple indexes. So the following query is in fact no permitted:

```
GET my_alias_name/my_type/AUwNrOZsm6BwwrmnodbW
```

Comment: It says `{
  "error" : "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Alias [data] has more than one indices associated with it [[data_2014-05-31, data_2014-06-26]], can't execute a single index op]",
  "status" : 400
}`

Comment: Even with the second request?

Comment: The second one works, thank you.  Although it is kind of slow.

Answer (score 16):

From Elasticsearch 5.1 the query looks like:

```
GET /my_alias_name/_search/
{
    "query": { 
        "bool": {
         "filter": {
                "term": {
                   "_id": "AUwNrOZsm6BwwrmnodbW"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Following [Elasticsearch 8.2 Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#docs-get), you can retrieve a single document by using GET API:

```
GET my-index-000001/_doc/0
```

Comment: This does not work if you have an alias with multiple indexes.  You get the error above "has more than one index associated with it".

Answer (score 3):

[7.2 version Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html) suggest:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "ids" : {
            "values" : ["1", "4", "100"]
        }
    }
}
```

Response should look like:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "indexwhatever",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "anyID",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "field1": "value1",
          "field2": "value2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to find a document with some internal id with curl:

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/_search?q=id:42&pretty'
```