# Elastic GET by ID query on rollover alias fails with ""Alias [...] has more than one indices associated with it..."

Tags: elasticsearch, alias, rollover

Our new rollover indices just rolled over. Now this query...

`GET http://my.elastic/system-logs/_doc/7e8017d8-0cb8-4b9e-b021-b2a4b4ac71c7`

...fails with this:

`"Alias [system-logs] has more than one indices associated with it [[system-logs-000002, system-logs-000001]], can't execute a single index op"`

But doing the same thing with `_search` works fine:

```
GET http://my.elastic/system-logs/_search/
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{"term": {"_id": "a1906f52-3957-4f4b-9b40-531422e3a04e"}}]
            }
        }
}
```

The exception comes from [this code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/023b6bbcf16e1e7108ef6feb4918c3691addb051/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/IndexNameExpressionResolver.java#L257-L266), which looks like there is an `allowAliasesToMultipleIndices` setting for this, but I haven't been able to find a place to set it.

We're on Elastic 6.8.

Comment: Was that answer helpful?

Answer (score 5):

In the first `http request`, you are just trying to find the doc with particular id on an index which in turn is an alias of more than one index.

That's the problem.

**Reason:**

`_doc` is a mapping type in elastic search. It is used to segregate documents in the same index. So it cannot check across the indices. It is deprecated. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747862/what-does-doc-represents-in-elasticsearch), [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008891/how-to-request-a-single-document-by-id-via-alias)

And you need to use `GET` request with the permitted queries[like your second example]  `(term, terms, match, query_string, simple_query_string).` [Refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html)